# Extract Certain Values From Text String

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to extract/isolate certain values in a string:

**String**

```
1:0:lon=288.987370,lat=42.353930,i=2035360,ix=1900,iy=949,val=36.2434
```

Say, for instance, I want to extract the value of `ix`, which is 1900.

I am guessing this can be accomplished through `awk` or `sed`.

**Attempted Code**

```
echo "1:0:lon=288.987370,lat=42.353930,i=2035360,ix=1900,iy=949,val=36.2434" | awk -F'=' '{print $4}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: [`grep -Po 'ix=\K\d+'`](https://ideone.com/U4w6lI)

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew!